# Turn off scroll event jQuery, without affecting scrollstop event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two events that work together:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){ //dothis });
```

&

```
$(window).on('scrollstop', function(){ //dothat });
```

At one point during the scrollstop event, (without having to explain - only that I am using this for flagging) I have to temporarily disable the scroll event:

```
$(window).off('scroll');
```

Only trouble is, this disables the scrollstop event too. How can I overcome this?

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                ready = true;
            });
            //Scroll function
            $(window).on('scrollstop', function(){
                $(window).off('scroll');
                if(ready){
                    ready = false;
                }
                else{
                    return;
                }
                var doc = document.documentElement;
                var top = (window.pageYOffset || doc.scrollTop) - (doc.clientTop || 0);
                if(top < 45){
                    $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: 0}, 100, 'swing');
                }
                else if(top <= 100){
                    $("html, body").stop().animate({scrollTop: 100}, 200, 'swing');
                }
                if(top > 100){
                    $("#mobileHeaderDivision").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#mobileMenu").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#mobileHeaderDivision").css({"position": "fixed", "top": "0", "left": "0"});
                    $("#mobileMenu").css({"position": "fixed", "top": "2px", "left": "0"});
                    $("#mobileHeaderDivision").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#mobileMenu").fadeIn("slow");
                }
                else{
                    $("#mobileHeaderDivision").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#mobileMenu").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#mobileHeaderDivision").css({"position": "relative", "top": "", "left": ""});
                    $("#mobileMenu").css({"position": "relative", "top": "", "left": ""});
                    $("#mobileHeaderDivision").fadeIn("slow");
                    $("#mobileMenu").fadeIn("slow");
                }
                $(window).on('scroll', function(){
                    ready = true;
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: how is your code constructed? can you post the complete structure of your jquery?

Comment: @threeFatCat Updated :)

Comment: Why do you even need the initial scroll event in the first place? What are you trying to do? I can assume that you are trying to determine when a person has transitioned from scrolling to not?

Comment: @Adjit No. What this actually does is fix the menu to the top if they scroll past the header. Otherwise, unfit it and put it below the header. Trouble is, scrollstop fires more than once causing fade toggles repetitively.

Comment: So basically, you are trying to have a sticky header that will stick to the top of the page when the user has scrolled past the header?

Comment: @Adjit correct :)

Comment: So what is the point of `scrollStop` then? Do you want to do something specifically when the user stops scrolling? Or are you just looking to have a sticky header and thats it?

Comment: @Adjit you'll also notice the function corrects a user's scroll (lines 16-21) whereby it will either be at the top, or below the header. Then the sticky menu will take effect anywhere below the header

Comment: It's hard for me to visualize what you have currently going on. Could you make a fiddle that illustrates  the issue?

Comment: @Adjit Hi I solved it having played around with it more. Basically I separated the two different tasks. One task is sticking the menu, the other is scrolling effects. My original question however which I'm still interested to know an answer to is how can I turn off a scroll event without turning off scrollstop?